# Property names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, literals, string-literals

I have a question that has been really bugging me for quite a while and I cannot seem to find any resources that cover the topic. How can property names in JavaScript be string literals or numeric literals?

```
var obj = {
    "bar": "foobar",
    "foo": function() { return bar; }
}
```

This topic has bugged me ever since I learned about it a few years ago. I don't know where to get more in-depth information or what this is even called. I not confused on how this is set up as I know that a new object is being creating with members, bar & foo and then its assigned to the obj variable.

You cannot create a variable like var "bar" = "foobar"; because you'll get a syntax error. How is it valid for object literals? Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `var bar = 'foobar';` can't work in your case?

Comment: That's the way the syntax works.

Comment: `obj['property']` syntax requires it.

Comment: Your example doesn't have a numeric literal, and both the given examples are valid property names. I personally don't understand what you're after.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals

Comment: @Phix I'm trying to understand how properties can be literals? Like, I want to try to dive deeper into and actually try to grasp it more. I'm a little confused myself and I'm trying to clear it up. I know I didn't put in any numeric literals in the example because I was just mentioning it.

Comment: I recommend reading ["_JavaScript - the Good Parts_"](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742).  After a couple chapters you'll understand stuff like this completely.

Comment: I see your point, but the fact that one can use string literals, i.e. any string value, shouldn't be so disconcerting. There's a lot of information available from users on SO here, much smarter than I ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaScript, property names are *String* values - any *String* values. That's just how the language is specified.

The relevant production:

```
PropertyName :  
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral
```

If an identifier, or a numeric literal is supplied, it is converted to a string value (SV).

See: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

So, for example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: true, // the name of this property becomes 'foo'
    'bar': true, // the name of this property becomes 'bar'
    123: true // the name of this property becomes '123'
};
```

---

You can even use the empty string as a property name:

```
var obj = {
    '': 'foo'
};

obj[''] // 'foo'
```

Comment: I think your on to something. I'm trying to grasp this better. The property names are auto-assumed as string values no matter if you pass in a identifier it'll be auto-quoted by the language. Why must you always quote the properties when write jSON? Is it because of how the others languages read it?

Comment: @W3Geek If you provide an identifier, its corresponding string value is used as the property name. There are no quotes here, as quotes only exist in string *literals* (source code), whereas here, the identifier is converted into a string *value* (memory) directly. *** JSON is more restrictive for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript object literals are hashmap implementations: i.e., key-value pairs. The keys can be represented either in quotes or without quotes.

That said, if you want to access a property as a string, you use the syntax below:

`obj[str]`

But if you want to access a property by its name, you use

`obj.name`

Answer (score 2):

The object literal syntax you are using [is just part of JavaScript's syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).  You can use numeric or string literal as a property name as well as any valid variable name as a property name.  Note that invalid variable names must be wrapped in quotes, but can still be property names (numeric literals being an exception).

That is, you can have `obj = {'"': value}`, i.e. a quote, as a valid object property name.  However, if you left off the apostrophes there it would be a syntax error.

The variable name syntax, e.g. `{nameWithoutQuotes: "value"}` is allowed, as far as I can tell, for convenience.  It has no special meaning and is treated as if it were a string literal property name.  It would look very odd to have `"` everywhere in an object literal definition, and it also makes sense when using similar accessor syntax.  For example:

```
obj = {"with quotes": "q", withoutQuotes: "x"};
obj["with quotes"];
obj.withoutQuotes;
```

Note that the method of access with a property name that requires quotes also requires quotes whereas when quotes are not required access can be done without them.

As for why `"obj" = "string"` is not allowed, other than the fact that it is invalid syntax, that is because the `"obj"` literal does not create a reference in memory that can be assigned to.  The `obj = {}` notation creates a reference that is stored in `obj` and memory is allocated for each of its properties as described by the literal syntax.  You could make a similar statement about `obj = "string";`

---

It may also be worth nothing that the quotes cannot be omitted from a [JSON](http://json.org/) string for property names.  Many parsers will not allow it.

Comment: I think many parsers will not allow it because identifiers in JavaScript are meant strictly for the JavaScript language... if you get what I mean.

Comment: If any JSON parser allows omission of the quotes, that parser is not implementing the JSON standard.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see that it is absolutely valid you just have to recall that objects are associative arrays , ie

```
 foo.bar === foo['bar']
```

In this case keys of associative array are any strings.